# How to access model data of type List having multiple item in each class in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter

I am making a simple app which has a model with 2 items in it. I want to access the list in `listView` builder but it gives an error:

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'FirstSem'.
> lib/main.dart:72 - 'FirstSem' is from
> 'package:project/model/model.dart' ('lib/model/model.dart').
> package:project/model/model.dart:1 Try correcting the operator to an
> existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator. trailing:
> Text(student[index].code)

Suggest me a good way to access it. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

**model.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstSem {
  String? title;
  String? code;
  FirstSem({this.title,this.code});
}
List <FirstSem> subject=[
  FirstSem(title: "MatheMatics",code: "MTH162"),
  FirstSem(title:"Physice",code:"Phy162"),
  FirstSem(title:"Digital Logic",code:"csc 162"),
  FirstSem(title:"C Programming",code:"csc 159"),
  FirstSem(title:"Introduction of Information Technology",code:"csc 160"),
];
```

`main.dart`

```
ListView.builder(itemCount: 5, itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return ListTile(
    title: Text(FirstSem[index].title),
    trailing: Text(FirstSem[index].code),
  );
})
```

Comment: Could you show me your detail error you got?

Comment: : Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'FirstSem'.
lib/main.dart:72
- 'FirstSem' is from 'package:project/model/model.dart' ('lib/model/model.dart').
package:project/model/model.dart:1
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  trailing: Text(student[index].code),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This is very simple to solve ✔️

You're trying to access item at index `index` of a `dart Class`. This is only possible on Lists

- Changing your `Text(FirstSem[index].title)` to `Text(subject[index].title)` and
- Setting your `itemCount` to `subject.length` will definitely solve your problem

Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

`FirstSem` is class, not object. Change the `FirstSem` to `subject` list like this

```dart
ListView.builder(
              itemCount:subject.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    final _subject = subject[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(_subject.title),
                      trailing: Text(_subject.code),
                    );
                  })
```

Comment: adding required keyword,it solved the problem